# R how to pass a list of Factors to a function in the same way as a DataFrame Factor column

Tags: r

I have a function that operates fine on slices of a dataframe which includes a factor column.
Id like to be able to run this also on manually specified lists (or some other structure) of the factor. However I cant seem to create an argument that I can reference in the same way. 
I have to reference a list with [[]] but the dataframe column works with [].

e.g. Id like to be able to pass this, but then function requires [[]] as its a list of lists.

```
list(NXT,NXT)[1]
[[1]]
[1] NXT
Levels: NXT NYT
```

something like rep, creates the right form of data , but I cant specify an arbitrary list easily.

```
rep(NXT,2)[1]
[1] NXT
Levels: NXT NYT
```

Surely theres an obvious way to create this explicitly the same way as rep is doing it internally?

Full clarification after comments.

```
    > mydata
  col1 col2
1    1    A
2    2    B
3    3    C
```

Some aliases

```
 A<-mydata$col2[1]

 B<-mydata$col2[2]

 C<-mydata$col2[3]
```

test function to illustrate

```
tfun<-function(fcts){
  str(fcts);
  length(fcts)
}
```

1 calling with the column

```
tfun(mydata$col2)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 2 3
[1] 3
```

2 calling with a repeat passes the same data type.

```
tfun(rep(A,2))
 Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1
[1] 2
```

3 but calling with a list is different.

```
tfun(list(A,B))
List of 2
 $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1
 $ : Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 2
[1] 2
```

4 call with a vector loses the factor info.

```
tfun(c(A,B))
 int [1:2] 1 2
[1] 2
```

The question is how can I call my existing function  with an arbitrary "list/set" of factors but pass the same data type as  1 & 2. (2 shows the datastructure exists, but what is it? , how can I create it easily?)

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Data.frames are lists so the statement that "I have to reference a list with [[]] but the dataframe column works with []" is wrong or deserves clarification. For example `cars` is a data.frame (list) and `cars["speed"]` returns a data.frame (list). To return a vector (list item) you have to use `cars[["speed"]]`.

Comment: Took a look at the source of "rep" and can replicate it with t1<-structure(c(A,B), class = class(A) , levels = levels(A) )
> t1
[1] A B
Levels: A B C    , so I can solve it, but is there a nicer more normal syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

Dug into source of "rep" and can create a structure that solves the issue

```
structure(c(A,B), class = class(A) , levels = levels(A) )
```

so

```
str(structure(c(A,A), class = class(A) , levels = levels(A) ))
 Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1
```

Which gives me what I want, still wonder if theres a better/more normal syntax.